# its possible replace with variable in groovy (java regex )?

Tags: regex, string, groovy

for example replace with varible group replacement

```
 def x=2

  "var1var2".replaceAll(/var(.*?)var(.+)/ , '$${x}' )
```

for obtain 2

Comment: You want to change the name of a variable in the code of a running program from within the code of that program? No, that's not possible. Why do you want to do this? Is it because you have many variables (var1, var2, var3, etc..) and you want to choose which one to use based on another variable (x)? If it is, then you want an array, a List, a Map or some other collection abstract data type.

Comment: Variable group? Do you mean capture group?
Please elaborate, your question is currently unclear. @PaulHicks This comment was for the OP, not sure why it tagged you. Ignore that notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you want:

```
"var1var2".replaceAll(/var(.*?)var(.+)/ , "\$${x}")
```

That will return the second group, so `2`

A better example (with only one `2` in it would be)

```
"var3var4".replaceAll(/var(.*?)var(.+)/ , "\$${x}")
```

That will return 4